# Merge two columns of a JavaFX TreeTableView

Tags: javafx, cell, treetableview

Im trying to implement the **Column Span** of a **TreeTableView** Shown in the *Cell* Section of the TreeTableView wiki. But theres no documentation in how to do so.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Wiki: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/TreeTableView+User+Experience+Documentation

Comment: You might find this article useful: http://fxexperience.com/2012/10/cell-spanning-in-tableview/ but I have to admit that I never applied that to TreeTables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open Ticket for that: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24747 or if you have no account there, there is a description here: http://fxexperience.com/2012/10/cell-spanning-in-tableview/

Long story short: It is planned but neither implemented nor a version when it will be released.

But you may use [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/), they have a [SpreadsheetView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) that has the functionality.